# See bluetooth transfer progress from phone to computer in terminal or other generic way

Tags: linux-mint, terminal, xfce, bluetooth, android

In Linux Mint 19.2 Xfce I want to transfer a rather big file (1.5 GB) from Android to the computer: it's big considering the fact that I have to do it by bluetooth.

I have connected the two devices and shared the file, I see the transfer on Android but (after selecting "Accept" for the transfer) I see nothing on the computer. Maybe this is dependent on the limitations of the desktop and its bluetooth manager.

But is there a way to show in terminal or other generic way the transfer progress?